# How to drag and pan on a large image after input range zoom?

Tags: javascript, zooming, pan

So I have a large map file (just a big image) that displays at 100% on page load, then I have range slider to zoom in and out which I have working correctly. However, I'm not sure how to add panning (click and drag with mouse) after the image is zoomed in on. How do I add panning to the image after the user zooms in? If possible, would also be nice to be able to use the left mouse button OR click and hold the scroll wheel to drag.

I did some searching but I didn't find an example that used it with a range slider or it had jQuery. I'd like to just use vanilla JS.

css

```
        #map {
            cursor: grab;
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 100%;
            max-width: 8500px;
        }

        #map-slider-div {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 15px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #map-div {
            text-align: center;
        }
```

html

```
    <div id="map-div">
        <img id="map" src="worldmap.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div id="map-slider-div">
        <input id="map-slider" type="range" min="300" max="8500" value="300">
    </div>
```

JS

```
    const init = () => {
        let mapSlider = document.querySelector('#map-slider');
        mapSlider.addEventListener('change', zoomMap);
    }

    const zoomMap = () => {
        let map = document.querySelector('#map');
        let mapSliderVal = document.querySelector('#map-slider').value;
        map.style.width = mapSliderVal + 'px';
    }

    window.onload = init;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok kind of got it working to how I want, New init method:

```
    const init = () => {

        let mapSlider = document.querySelector('#map-slider');
        mapSlider.addEventListener('change', zoomMap);

        let map = document.querySelector('#map');
        let mapDiv = document.querySelector('#map-div');
        map.addEventListener('mousedown', start_drag);
        mapDiv.addEventListener('mousemove', while_drag);
        mapDiv.addEventListener('mouseup', stop_drag);

        var img_ele = null,
            x_cursor = 0,
            y_cursor = 0,
            x_img_ele = 0,
            y_img_ele = 0;

        function start_drag() {
            img_ele = this;
            x_img_ele = window.event.clientX - map.offsetLeft;
            y_img_ele = window.event.clientY - map.offsetTop;
        }

        function stop_drag() {
            img_ele = null;
        }

        function while_drag() {
            var x_cursor = window.event.clientX;
            var y_cursor = window.event.clientY;
            if (img_ele !== null) {
                img_ele.style.left = (x_cursor - x_img_ele) + 'px';
                img_ele.style.top = (window.event.clientY - y_img_ele) + 'px';

                console.log(img_ele.style.left + ' - ' + img_ele.style.top);

            }
        }

    }
```

But is there someway I can make it so the image can't be moved off the edge of the screen? if you're at the bottom of the image and try to zoom out the map can disappear sometimes. Or maybe someway to reset coordinates of the image on zoom?

EDIT: Also answered this... close enough anyways. Reset the top and left of the image on each zoom so it won't ever go completely out of view:

```
const zoomMap = () => {
        let map = document.querySelector('#map');
        map.style.top = 0;
        map.style.left = 0;
        let mapSliderVal = document.querySelector('#map-slider').value;
        map.style.width = mapSliderVal + 'px';
    }
```

Would love for it to zoom in and out on current/last position though.. For some reason it always zooms to the top left?